# media_handle_sideload() halts when not logged in as admin

Tags: wordpress

Function runs fine to download and attach video to post when I run it manually from the admin area. However when I try to run it from the front end or as a cron, it downloads the tmp file but halts before moving the file, no error messages are returns. I am including /includes/image.php, /includes/file.php and /includes/media.php

Any ideas on how to fix this?